# Angular - after deleting from ngRepeat, remaining items don't slide smoothly but rather snap/jump into place

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm using the AngularJS v1.4.8 and I included/injected ngAnimate in my controller.

I am building a dynamic list using ngRepeat, which is bound to an array.
Adding and updating items in the list works perfectly and animations run as expected.
However, when I delete an item from the list, all trailing elements (i.e. elements below the deleted item) snap into position.
I would like the trailing elements to gracefully slide into place.

Just to reiterate. Currently when I delete an item, the trailing items snap into the white space left by the element that is being deleted. I want the trailing items to smoothly slide into the white space.

I've tried playing around with max-height, setting it to a fixed value for enter and then to 0 for leave. This doesn't work at all - nothing happens. (i.e. no shrinking of any kind).

Which part of the CSS would handle this?

- ng.enter
- ng.leave
- ng.move (sneaky suspicion that it won't be this as most example refer to drag&drop functionality)

### **View**

This is what the HTML "list" looks like:

`<div ng-repeat="cItem in commentData.comments" class="animate-repeat">`

### **CSS**

Here is my current CSS

```
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-move
{
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave
{
    -webkit-animation:0.5s fadeOut;
    -moz-animation:0.5s fadeOut;
    -o-animation:0.5s fadeOut;
    animation:0.5s fadeOut;

    opacity:1;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active
{
    opacity:1;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active
{
    opacity: 0;
}


/* Did this for all platforms - not showing here though */
fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

### **Screen dumps**

Before delete
[image]

While deleting
[image]

Comment: What does `fadeOut` CSS anim refers to ?

Comment: How do you delete them? Perhaps it would be good, to hide the element when a user clicks the delete button (`height: 0` and the animation), and when it completes, a callback removes the element from the array.

Comment: @enguerranws, I've updated the CSS

Comment: @AlexSzabó, I delete the item from the array (after deleting from the db via a service). I will def give your suggestion a bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space:nowrap;
} 

.animate.ng-leave.animate.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}

.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, 
.animate.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
}

.ng-move{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thanx for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work. Now none of the animations work.  I replaced my current CSS with your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You should add styles for slide transition (margin, absolute position or transform inside block with overflow hidden). 
And besides that if you and "track by" to your ng-repeat directive you will be able to create reorder animation. Without track by angular tracking items in array by $index, and after deleting second one third one will be just rendered on second position. If you give angular some unique key to track items it will know that third one become second and won't rerendered it, but move to second position. Hope this will help.